Determine the dimension of the space of r-linear forms
I study mathematics as a hobby and have no access to a professor who can check on my work, so I am asking for corrections to my work in this site. I apologize in advance if my approach turns out to be incomprehensible.
The following is from Elon Lages Lima's Analysis Course, vol. II (translated): 

Let $\mathcal{L}_{r}(E;F)$ denote the space of r-linear forms (not necessarily alternating) from E to F. From a basis in E, determine a base for $\mathcal{L}_r(E;\mathbb{R})$.

I started this way: For a given list of r elements $\sigma_n = \{i_1,...,i_r\} \subset\{1,...,n\}$ (in which the terms need not be in any order and might repeaat themselves), write $e_{\sigma_n}=\{e_{i_1},...,e_{i_r}\}$. There are then $n^r$ such lists. 

The book states the following theorem: "Let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be a base for the vector space E. For each r-list $\sigma = \{i_1,\dots,i_r\} \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$, choose a vector $w_{\sigma}\in F$. There is a unique r-linear mapping $\phi:E^r\to F$ such that $\phi(e_{i_1},\dots,e_{i_r}) = w_\sigma$". 

I then define the "base linear form" $\phi_{\sigma_n}$ to be the uniquely defined linear form s.t. $\phi_{\sigma_n}(e_{\sigma_{m}})=1$ if $m = n$ and $=0$ if $m\ne n$ (as guarenteed to exist by the theorem above), and there are $n^r$ of them. Then any linear form $\psi: E^r\to F$ will be s.t. $\psi=\sum_{i=1}^{n^r}\psi(e_{\sigma_i})\phi_{\sigma_i}$.

Is this correct?

So an $r$-list is an ordered $r$-tuple? I would probably avoid the set brackets notation.

Yes. Thanks for the feedback!
